# Does Windows folder in all CAPS cause problems such as failing Major Windows Updates?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1909

After a series of failed updates from Windows 10 1909 to 2004 or even 21H1 with update assistant, I was figuring out what caused the updates to fail. Besides it's pretty old installation of Windows 10 since 2016, I also realised the Windows System Folder is all in Caps which does not seem to be normal as all my other machines uses "Windows" as the folder.

[image]

#### Partition layout

[image]

#### Diagnostic logs

SetupDiagResults.log : https://gist.github.com/Cerlancism/51ae706abbf09be7ee55cc87ef8be2fb
Some minidumps (many months old and probably not update relavant): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbMyc9QFyVZEpZ3ReNiHhps1oieLNru8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Windows is generally not case-sensitive for folder names. So Windows and WINDOWS mean the same thing to the Windows Operating System. So CAPS is almost for sure not your issue.

Comment: Please add the errors you're getting to your question.

Comment: @harrymc 0xc1900101, after the update and restart, the Windows is not updated and showed the failed update notification. Quick googling show this is driver issue, but I don't think it is really true as that machine has been successfully updating since 1511

Comment: Windows need drivers to be up to date, and in some systems (from as far back as 1511) need BIOS updates as well. Run the Driver Update App for your machine and update ALL drivers.

Comment: Try to follow [this advice](https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/0xc1900101.html). You could also go to folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`, where you should find some `.dmp` files, zip up a couple of the most recent ones, and post it online for us to analyze (dropbox, onedrive etc).

Comment: Provide the log for SetupDiag

Comment: When long file name support was introduced, to make MS-Dos filenames which are only upper case look nice, explorer shows as lower case with the initial letter capitalised. If the name is lower case or mixed case it shows as is. This only applies to files with short filenames. without a long filename. Short filenames are turned off by default in Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound https://gist.github.com/Cerlancism/51ae706abbf09be7ee55cc87ef8be2fb

Comment: What partitions does your system have?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting temporary commentary

Comment: @Ramhound Edited question and added partition layout.

Comment: @harrymc I found and posted the dumps in the edited question but i think those are many months old from probably non update relevant BSODs

Comment: What type of Bluetooth device do you have in your system?

Comment: @Ramhound Intel Wireless Bluetooth, quite recently updated to 22.50.0.4

Comment: The `.dmp` files are indeed too old. Try to find some information in the Event Viewer. For the error in SetupDiagResults.log, try Microsoft's advice [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-help-with-windows-10-upgrade-and-installation-errors-ea144c24-513d-a60e-40df-31ff78b3158a) for that error code. Microsoft says that this "is usually a driver error".